# How to output call object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

while I was reading a javascript book, I read the following sentence.

"The call object is initialized with a property named arguments that refers to the Arguments object for the function"

am I allow to output the structure (or values?) of a call object in javascript using console.log or alert() method??

when people say 'a call object', is it a concept or an object?

Comment: I believe the Activation Object is another name for the object you're looking for, and it's inaccessible to your code. (See @Matthew-Crumley's answer). 
If you're trying to detect the object that called your function (NOT the function that called your function), you can use "this", assuming the function was not bound or otherwise strangely closed over in a way that altered the expected "this" (See: Kyle's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they are referring to the object calling the method/function.

This can be referenced by the `this` keyword

```
<a onclick="foo()">click me</a>

function foo(){
  this.style.color='#cc0000';
  alert(arguments.length);
}
```

This code would change the text color of the anchor to '#cc0000' and alert 0.

Answer (score 3):

The "call object" is referred to as an "activation object" in the ECMAScript specs, and it cannot be accessed directly. This allows ECMAScript/JavaScript engines to implement it in an optimal way because they only have to ensure that it always behaves correctly, even if there's not literally an object with argument property, properties for variables, etc.

Here's the description from the spec (with emphesis added):

> ### [10.1.6 Activation Object](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.6)
>
> When control enters an execution context for
>   function code, an object called the
>   activation object is created and
>   associated with the execution context.
>   The activation object is initialised
>   with a property with name arguments
>   and attributes { DontDelete }. The
>   initial value of this property is the
>   arguments object described below.
>
> The activation object is then used as
>   the variable object for the purposes
>   of variable instantiation.
>
> ***The activation object is purely a
>   specification mechanism. It is
>   impossible for an ECMAScript program
>   to access the activation object.*** It
>   can access members of the activation
>   object, but not the activation object
>   itself. When the call operation is
>   applied to a Reference value whose
>   base object is an activation object,
>   null is used as the this value of the
>   call.

Comment: I believe this is the real answer to the question in the question's current form. Given the way O'Reilly presents this "object" in http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_06.htm#jscript4-CHP-4-SECT-6.2 relating to "Where are local variables stored?", they refer to it as the "Call Object". This, to me, best translates to the "Activation Object" mentioned in this answer. The "calling object" is a different concept, in my understanding.