# calling inner-function dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript

is it possible to call inner function dynamically(by it's name)?

e.g.

```
function a(){
    function b(){..}
    var funcName = "b";
    //calling the function b somehow using funcName
}
```

I know it's possible by using eval, but I rather not using eval, if b was global function I could use window[funcName] or global[funcName]...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to access `b` through its name (`"b"`) magically, without recording the name `b` in a separate structure.

You are correct that global variables are properties of the global object, generally accessed through the identifier `window` in web environments.  It's fun how that works actually, as `window` is a property of the global object pointing to itself, but, that is off topic.

Local variables are properties of an object, too -- the *call object*.  This object exists temporarily during the call.  If you could get to the call object directly, then you *would* be able to say something like `theCallObject[funcName]`, because the nested function is still a local variable, although hoisted.  Alas, this object is not directly accessible, so you basically have to revert to the techniques shown in the earlier answers.

Here is an SO question with info: [How to output call object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177271/how-to-output-call-object-in-javascript).

I suppose it is possible to write a JS engine with an extension permitting access to the call object, much like Mozilla gave us the non-standard `__proto__`.

Comment: Because I didn't think this was very clear: while *local variables* are stored in an object -- of sorts -- *this detail is not exposed in JavaScript* and although is talked about in such in the specification it may be implemented differently -- for optimization and closure minimizing, for instance -- due to not being exposed. (The only exception is `arguments[n]`, where `n` is a numeric index, which are function parameters, not `var`iables).

Comment: I'll buy that, @pst.  That fact that the call object is discussed in the spec does not mean it has to actually exist in actual implementation as a JavaScript object.  It exists to help describe the semantics.  Fair enough.  Totally.  I'll stand by my remark that **if** access to it **were** granted by some implementation then one **would** be able to do what the OP wanted.  As it stands now, there is no such magic, I believe. +1 for your technical comment.

Comment: It would indeed be possible in that case ;-) Python has the ill-mentioned `locals()` function which can do just that which is proposed (with the warning that the python run-time makes no guarantee that changes will be propagated.) On another note the linked SO question/answer mixes up the "call object" -- I use quotes because it is used in a different context in post and answers -- and the *activation object*. (The *activation object* is not `this`.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can declare it differently, and it's not so hard:

```
function a(){
    this.b = function() {...};

    // dynamic access
    var funcName = "b";
    this[funcName]();

    // still need static access?
    var b = this.b;
    b();
}
```

You can mix it up, of course.  But Functions are just objects (both `a` **and** `b`), so they can be assigned, moved around, and even have instance members.

Comment: That will work differently depending on the invocation context of `a` (e.g. what `this` points to) so I would not recommend that construct.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on OverZealous's answer that does not muck with `this`:

```
function a(){
    function b(){..}
    var internalFuncs = {"b": b}
    var funcName = "b"
    internalFuncs[funcName]()
}
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
var a = (function() {
    return {
        b: function() { alert("b"); },
        c: function() { alert("c"); },
        d: function() { alert("d"); }
    }
})();

a["b"]();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raSKW/